# Watson Assistant Webhook returns always null

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm testing the Assistant feature of using Webhooks and by some reason I don't receive any output. My Cloud-Function code looks so:

```
async function main(params) {
    switch (params.action){
        case 'bills':
            var resp_final = [
                {
                    value: 'Rechnung RN1074801326',
                    datum: '28.02.2021',
                    total_preis: '710€'
                },
                {
                    value: 'Rechnung RN8243559014',
                    datum: '01.03.2021',
                    total_preis: '130€'
                }
            ];  
            return { elements: resp_final };
            break;
        //DEFAULT RETURN
        default:
            return {no: 'default'};
    }
}
```

And I invoke it from the assistant like so:
[image]

As you can see, only **[0].value** gets printed to the console. Even if I don't specify any attribute there is still no result on the console. However, I tested the Cloud function with parameters and it's working (it shows the array without problems). Any reason why this might occurs?

Comment: Have you checked the Cloud Function activation record? Is the webhook called? What if you use `<? $webhook_result_1 ?>` as responds, just for testing?

Comment: Hey Henrik. I managed it - I just basically need to go deeper in the $webjooh_result_1 variable. But I have a different problem now - I can't instantiate a IamAuthenticator in the Cloud function: ```Cannot find module 'ibm-watson/auth'```

Comment: that's a different question - check which modules are available per runtime

Comment: I've wrote another post, can you check it, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66515480/ibm-cloud-functions-cant-find-ibm-watson-auth-package